# Connection problems with cURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl, panoramio

Good day,

I have a web service that makes multiple cURL requests via PHP to different external APIs including panoramio.com, flickr.com, worldweatheronline.com, etc. Everything worked well for a year or so but few weeks ago the percent of failed connections went through the sky on some hosts (panoramio.com and worldweatheronline.com are among the leaders with total 6% of failed requests each). Immediate consequent request to the same host can be successful or failed with the same probability.

So I trying to figure out what happened and how should I fixed, maybe some system update or newer PHP version are broken...

Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS, PHP 5.5.16 with cURL 7.22.0 (php-fpm) on nginx.

cURL options are: connection timeout 5 seconds, total timeout 60 seconds, SSL verify host and peer are both disabled, IP resolve forced to IPv4. Here are some debug information of failed requests:

```
[url] => http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?set=public&order=popularity&from=0&to=21&size=medium&minx=82.685329&miny=25.748195&maxx=82.695311&maxy=25.757185
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 5.004513
    [namelookup_time] => 3.1E-5
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 173.194.71.141
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 80
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
)
```

Or:

```
(
    [url] => http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?key=API_KEY_REMOVED&format=js&q=38.25000,20.60000&num_of_days=7
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 158
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 67.623743
    [namelookup_time] => 2.4E-5
    [connect_time] => 1.15904
    [pretransfer_time] => 1.159041
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 46.37.171.96
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 80
    [local_ip] => IP_REMOVED
    [local_port] => PORT_REMOVED
)
```

As you can see connection process is terminated in different states but DNS name is always resolved correctly.

Any ideas how to debug and/or solve this issue will be really appreciated as I don't know where to dig anymore :/

Comment: for panoramio; 
it says that there is a limit daily (http://www.panoramio.com/api/data/api.html)

do you think you make more than 100K requests per day?

Comment: @engvrdr No, I don't think so as we do only about 70 per minute which is roughly 100000 requests daily. That mean that at the end of the day some requests may fail due to this limits but requests fails fairly randomly during whole day :/

Comment: 70 requests per minute makes 100.800 per day (24 hours) they may be checking the amount you made last 24 hours so this may cause randomness on failing.

Comment: @engvrdr Hmm, makes sense, I'll try to pause requests for a while a see if that will help. Thanks!